# Can you declare a parameter that assigns a value to a variable with a different name?

Tags: powershell

When you declare a parameter, you provide the name of a variable, and that name is used as the name of the parameter on the command line. However, I don't always want to use the same naming convention for script variables as I do for the names of command line parameters.

For example:

```
function Some-Function {
  param (
    $some_variable
  )
  ...
}
```

Invoking `Some-Function -some_variable <value>` assigns  to $some_variable. What if I want the name of the parameter used when invoking the function to be different than the name of the variable I use in the body of the function? For example, invoking `Some-Function -ElegantName <value>` would assign  to a variable called $some_variable?

Sure, I could do something like this:

```
Some-Function {
  param (
    $ElegantName
  )
  $some_variable = $ElegantName
}
```

But that seems like an ugly kludge, to declare one set of variables in the parameter declaration and then reassign them to new variables so the variables in the script don't have to have the same names as the parameters. Is there a way to do it in the declaration?

Note that `[alias('ElegantName')]$some_variable` isn't a good solution, because "some_variable" is still the name that shows up in tab completion.

Comment: Why was a valid answer removed? Still. As I said in my comment there: your current solution isn't ugly. That's what the Begin block or the start of the script is for. But why do you need this? Good code is readable, and good parameters are self explanatory.  So if you need to rename a parameter it usually means that you used a terrible name or want to make your code harder to understand.

Comment: I don't know why my answer was removed. It is in fact an answer to the question: "Is there a way to rename a variable in the declaration without using an alias?" The answer to that question is "no." My follow-up question is also valid: How is simply assigning a new variable the content of the passed parameter any different? This solution (simply assign a new variable) seems perfectly readable and straightforward to me.

Bill

Comment: @Graimer I disagree. It's not simply a matter of whether the names are inherently "good" or "bad", and the only reason to use a different names for different purposes is that one is "terrible" and you want to use a "better" one elsewhere. Different naming conventions are used in different places. In fact, readability and consistency is the very purpose of using different names for the parameter and the variable it assigns, if the naming convention you're using for variables in your code doesn't align with the naming convention for PowerShell parameters.

Comment: For example, **$str_some_name** may be a great name for a variable in the code, if that's the kind of naming convention you're using, but it would be an ugly name for a parameter, which would be better named **-SomeName**. Why should the convention for parameter names used on the command line dictate the convention for variables in the code, or vice versa? Most other languages don't tie the parameter name to the name of the variable it assigns.

Comment: @Bill Stewart It just seems odd to me that PowerShell ties the two together. Especially if you have a large number of parameters, I think it would be more elegant to define everything in the parameter declaration (e.g. `[parameter(Name="ParameterName")][boolean]$bool_var_name"`) rather than begin your code with a bunch of assignment statements just to use different naming conventions in the code than in the command line syntax. I don't know why your answer was removed, I had nothing to do with it. In any case, it does seem that the answer is just "no". Not a huge deal, just kind of annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I decided to replace actual variable names with its aliases and do not touch existing code. For example it was:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][alias("ServiceAccount")][string]$svc_user='somedata'
```

And it became:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][alias("svc_user")][string]$ServiceAccount='somedata'
```

UPD.
Unfortunately, this doesn't work - aliases are not recognised in the code. I had to add more code to automatically create variables with alias name and assign original value to it:

```
$standardparameters = @("Verbose", "Debug", "ErrorAction", "WarningAction", "ErrorVariable", "WarningVariable","OutVariable","OutBuffer","PipelineVariable")
$allparameters = ((Get-Command -Name $MyInvocation.InvocationName).Parameters).values  
$customparameters = @()
 ForEach ($par in $allparameters) { if ($par.name -notin $standardparameters) {$customparameters += $par}}
ForEach ($par in $customparameters) { foreach ($al in $par.Aliases) {try{Set-Variable -Name $al -Value $(Get-Variable $par.Name -ValueOnly) -ErrorAction stop} Catch {new-Variable -Name $al -Value $(Get-Variable $par.Name -ValueOnly)}}}
```

Please note, the code can only be executed when launching the script or function itself. If you try to select code and launch selection, you will receive an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use advanced parameters, here is an exemple where I alias the french parameter name for "file" :

```
Function TestAdvParam
{
  Param ([Alias("Fichier")]
         [string]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
         $file)
  Write-Host $file
}

TestAdvParam -file "coucou 1"
TestAdvParam -fichier "coucou 2"
```

Have a look to [about_functions_advanced_parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) (get-help)

**Note :** the target of aliases is to give a name that is easy to remember or use for the developper, so it's not so strange that they not appear in the autocompletion.

Comment: OP explicitly said he did not want to use an alias.

Comment: I think you overlooked the last paragraph, where I said that an alias isn't a good solution, because it's the variable name, not the alias, that shows up in tab completion at the command line.

Comment: @JPBlanc Im not sure what you just said really, but at least it was confusing.